# SignalR notification using SqlScaleoutConfiguration gives random exception for Rebus.Transport.TransactionContext not serializable

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, notifications, signalr, rebus

I use:
SignalR 2.2.2 in SqlScaleoutConfiguration 
Rebus 3.0.1

Some events stored in Rebus are handled by a notification hub and pushed to the clients using signalR.

Everything works fine, but this morning, after having published a new version, none of the clients received the "new version" message probably because of the following exception:

```
10:39:04.586| |ERROR| |ProcessId=8196| |ThreadId=5| |SignalR.SqlMessageBus| |Stream 0 : Error starting SQL notification listener: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type 'Rebus.Transport.TransactionContext' in Assembly 'Rebus, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.InternalGetSerializableMembers(RuntimeType type)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(Type type, StreamingContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitMemberInfo()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Write(WriteObjectInfo objectInfo, NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSerializer.SerializeMessageParts(ArrayList argsToSerialize)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.SmuggledMethodCallMessage..ctor(IMethodCallMessage mcm)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.SmuggledMethodCallMessage.SmuggleIfPossible(IMessage msg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage reqMsg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at System._AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDependency.CreateProcessDispatcher(_AppDomain masterDomain)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDependency.ObtainProcessDispatcher()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDependency.Start(String connectionString, String queue, Boolean useDefaults)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SqlServer.ObservableDbOperation.StartSqlDependencyListener()
```

The message in Rebus queue results as correctly handled.

The handler is this:

```
public async Task Handle(ApplicationVersionEvent message)
{
    await
        Clients.All.CheckApplicationVersion(new ApplicationCurrentVersionNotification
        {                    
            CurrentVersion = message.CurrentVersion
        });
}
```

It was resolved by a restart, but I need to understand what happened.

I similar issues are:

- https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3401
- https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3404
- [SQL Query Notifications do not always work in scaleout setup (SQL Server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28504712/sql-query-notifications-do-not-always-work-in-scaleout-setup-sql-server)
- https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/issues/493
- [Rebus, exception when creating AppDomain / Instance from async Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34021061/rebus-exception-when-creating-appdomain-instance-from-async-handler)

but I think this is not the same case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot this issue, but I solved it by a workaround a little later on.

The clue is that SqlMessageBus serializes the context when it is initialized and this happens the first time it is retrieved invoking GetHubContext, so I forced its initialization before executing any command.

```
    app.MapSignalR();

    var context = new OwinContext(app.Properties);
    var token = context.Get<CancellationToken>("host.OnAppDisposing");
    if (token != CancellationToken.None)
    {
        token.Register(() =>
        {
            log.Info("host.OnAppDisposing");
            // code to run when server shuts down
            BackendMessageBusConfig.DisposeContainers();
        });
    }

    // this code brings forward SignalR SqlMessageBus initialization 
    var forceInit = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();

    BackendMessageBusConfig.Register();
```

Answer (score 1):

It is really hard for me to tell you what's going on here besides what you have already discovered: SignalR *for some weird reason* seems to want to serialize the values stashed in the current execution context, and one of those values is Rebus' current transaction context.

As explained in the links you included, Rebus stores an "ambient transaction" this way when handling a message, allowing all of its own operations to be enlisted in the same unit of work.

You *could* use the approach explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34021143/6560), where the transaction context is temporarily removed in a safe way like this

```
public async Task Handle(SomeMessage message)
{
    var transactionContext = AmbientTransactionContext.Current;
    AmbientTransactionContext.Current = null;
    try
    {
        JuggleWithAppDomainsInHere();
    }
    finally
    {
        AmbientTransactionContext.Current = transactionContext;
    }
}
```

possibly moving relevant bits to the constructor/`Dispose` method respectively in a class that implements `IDisposable`, making for a smoother API:

```
using(new DismantleAmbientRebusStuff())
{
    JuggleWithAppDomainsInHere();
}
```

I think someone who knows a lot about SignalR would need to chime in if we were to find out what really happened.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I will implement a decorator for notification hub handlers because it can happen in whichever handled message.
Anyway the error is random and, luckily, rare so it takes time to say if the answer solves it.